# LocationManager inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, locationlistener

I'm trying to convert an `Activity` which uses `LocationListener` to a `Fragment`, using `LocationManager` like this:

protected LocationManager locationManager;

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
(...)
}
```

I'm having some problems with these methods (can't get rid of the errors):

```
if (location != null) {
    // location known:
    onLocationChanged(location); // Error here
}


boolean startLocationUpdates() {
    boolean result = false;
    for (final String provider : locationManager.getProviders(true)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2 * 1000, 0.0f,
                this); // Error here
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this); // Error here
    savePrefs();
}
```

**How can I use these methods inside a fragment?**

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the relationship between the `LocationManager` and the `LocationListener` that actually receives the updates. For example, onLocationChanged, where you indicate an error, is really a callback that the `LocationListener` you assign to that `LocationManager` uses to pass a new location object to your activity/fragment. It's not something you call yourself.

The way your `LocationListener` and `LocationManager` would interact is something like this. You'd have an instance of both within your fragment. `onActivityCreated` you would initilize both the `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` with the `LocationListener` implementing all the required callbacks below.

```
 locationListener = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            GeoPoint userLoc = processNewLocation(location);
            if(userLoc != null){
                Log.d("USERLOC", userLoc.toString());
                                    //do something with the location    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
```

Your `LocationListner` would then call onLocationChanged each time the locatino change met whatever critera you assigned at creation. Check the android docs for [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) for more details.